# PayPal IPN always invalid (PHP)

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to setup an IPN listener for PayPal IPNs, using their official code:

```
<?php
define("DEBUG", 1);
define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);
define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");

$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
    $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}

$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
  $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
  if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
  } else {
    $value = urlencode($value);
  }
  $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
  $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
  $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}

$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
  return FALSE;
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);

if(DEBUG == true) {
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

$cert = "cacert.pem";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);

$res = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0)
  {
  if(DEBUG == true) { 
    error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
  }
  curl_close($ch);
  exit;

} else {
    if(DEBUG == true) {
      error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
      error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}

$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
  if(DEBUG == true) {
    error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
  }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
  if(DEBUG == true) {
    error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
  }
}

?>
```

In the log file, it always says "Invalid IPN". Here is an example output of the log file:

```
[2016-06-11 13:24 UTC] HTTP request of validation request:POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1
Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com
Accept: */*
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 938
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 for IPN payload: cmd=_notify-validate&payment_type=instant&payment_date=Sat+Jun+11+2016+15%3A19%3A13+GMT+0200+%28Mitteleurop%E4ische+Sommerzeit%29&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=buyer%40paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John+Smith&address_country=United+States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San+Jose&address_street=123+any+street&business=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&residence_country=US&item_name1=something&item_number1=AK-1234&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&mc_gross_1=12.34&mc_handling=2.06&mc_handling1=1.67&mc_shipping=3.02&mc_shipping1=1.02&txn_type=cart&txn_id=823157700&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&test_ipn=1&verify_sign=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A4KcVHT4SiLbr-oHdZ0TwjgM6eI.
[2016-06-11 13:24 UTC] HTTP response of validation request: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 11 Jun 2016 13:24:37 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: c9MWDuvPtT9GIMyPc3jwol1VSlO=FgblhbT9L29XjCBcxDezDZ3FchWl0-_CdfSblPbaUTAsU8R3qrLki1UeqqDcWn9lANtLpLVAmM_JW3v3NSo2eoz0TNmLbwDaKJCA1Tz3uX1b29mz6TVb-vPwJpwMtG4dvbpxN_kaJtL9bBZy9MpMy0bkRSczpqOitQxcvrm8c4fxA7T40oq89MJjlv_bQjpeIFDb796eKPjNuME2lTZQ0Ob628isiyP20XizrcnDArVRQsmI0Nvfp6d0vqjj2g0PC6yNz75UkRVO0C7bRYABjVu-yIC_klODAGkK_sC9w5XY2XNtDEsO00Y7FEnacainOI6COAhUzQnFfpZ55dTRYPI_QYR_Hd_zq-Cg5N8eKS1GyxcHZYc_gcVvGjW6b3wkdXHgFZ4LiCWyiFBi2Sf4rLZ5rW__NzDfnHXSIK92ayGBneh4YBcqSnP7iTe; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; expires=Tue, 09-Jun-2026 13:24:37 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navcmd=_notify-validate; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navlns=0.0; expires=Mon, 11-Jun-2018 13:24:37 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: Apache=10.72.108.11.1465651477182662; path=/; expires=Mon, 04-Jun-46 13:24:37 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Connection: close
HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR: sandbox.slc
Paypal-Debug-Id: d9789fdb281e9
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D1880%26app%3Dappdispatcher%26TIME%3D353459287%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3Dsandbox.slc; Expires=Sat, 11 Jun 2016 13:54:37 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=14400
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

INVALID
[2016-06-11 13:24 UTC] Invalid IPN: cmd=_notify-validate&payment_type=instant&payment_date=Sat+Jun+11+2016+15%3A19%3A13+GMT+0200+%28Mitteleurop%E4ische+Sommerzeit%29&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=buyer%40paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John+Smith&address_country=United+States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San+Jose&address_street=123+any+street&business=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&residence_country=US&item_name1=something&item_number1=AK-1234&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&mc_gross_1=12.34&mc_handling=2.06&mc_handling1=1.67&mc_shipping=3.02&mc_shipping1=1.02&txn_type=cart&txn_id=823157700&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&test_ipn=1&verify_sign=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A4KcVHT4SiLbr-oHdZ0TwjgM6eI.
at+Jun+11+2016+15%3A19%3A13+GMT+0200+%28Mitteleurop%E4ische+Sommerzeit%29&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=buyer%40paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John+Smith&address_country=United+States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San+Jose&address_street=123+any+street&business=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&residence_country=US&item_name1=something&item_number1=AK-1234&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&mc_gross_1=12.34&mc_handling=2.06&mc_handling1=1.67&mc_shipping=3.02&mc_shipping1=1.02&txn_type=cart&txn_id=823157700&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&test_ipn=1&verify_sign=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A4KcVHT4SiLbr-oHdZ0TwjgM6eI.
```

I can't seem to find what's wrong. For me it looks like PayPal says its invalid even though I'm in the sandbox mode.

Comment: Interesting...if you look at the copy of the IPN in the "Invalid IPN" log line, a lot of the fields have been repeated.  I wonder what caused that?

Answer (score 0):

This is an intermittent problem with the IPN sandbox.  Please see my explanation here: [PayPal IPN simulator returning "INVALID" but I've followed the rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37679022/paypal-ipn-simulator-returning-invalid-but-ive-followed-the-rules/37755288#37755288)