# Paypal Third Party Shopping Cart Retrieve Information

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, shopping-cart

Hi I'm creating a third party shopping cart using paypal for my client and i need retrieve some information after the payment is confirmed. I need to send an email to the seller with the product information like color, font-family, font-size, size of the product. But i have no idea of how can i retrieve the payment confirm information from paypal and then send to the seller this email.

Does someone knows how or just could give me a hint?

Thanks.

Comment: PayPal can return all of the transaction data back to your script. The key is to know what type of PayPal payment process you are using and how to accept the return values. Are you using PayPal standard or PayPal Pro? They handle the return values differently.

Comment: I'm using paypal standard, and thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not on wordpress, you can still use IPN data: have a read here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

Note that Paypal's example code is not very good, and also that their IPN simulator is not currently working properly: [Paypal IPN continually returns invalid from Sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37917313/paypal-ipn-continually-returns-invalid-from-sandbox)

Answer (score 0):

The [PayPal IPN for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-ipn/) plugin will make that very simple for you.

Just install the plugin and create a basic hook in your theme's functions.php file (or create a simple custom plugin file).  The plugin has hooks so you can trigger based on any IPN, or based on the IPN transaction type or payment status.

Here is a [link to the general dev guide](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-ipn-wordpress-developer-guide/) and another [link specific to the hooks available](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-ipn-wordpress-hooks/).

You could have the IPN solution working and sending an email within minutes, so then it's just a matter of building your email body the way you want.